# Error when requesting review using SKStoreReviewController

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiscenedelegate, skstorereviewcontroller

When I use `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` to request a review from the Scene Delegate in my SwiftUI application, I get the following message:
`Error in UIKit client: -[UIWindow setScreen:] should not be called if the client adopts UIScene lifecycle. Call -[UIWindow setWindowScene:] instead.`.

I am using the following code in the scene delegate to request the review:

```
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "launchCount") == 10 {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: homeView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: windowScene)
        }
        else {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
        }
    }
}
```

This code is inside the `scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)` method of the Scene Delegate. The method for iOS 14 is working where the review is being requested from the `UIWindowScene`, but the method for earlier versions is not working and returns the message specified previously. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: `requestReview(in windowScene: UIWindowScene)` is available in only iOS 14 or higher. Since I am also supporting iOS 13 in my app and `requestReview()` is deprecated as of iOS 14 , I am using the availability check. iOS 13 and earlier uses `requestReview()` which returns the error message as stated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my small wrapper around SKStoreReviewController which solves this problem.

```
import SwiftUI
import AppReview

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("SwiftUI")
        }.onAppear {
            AppReview.requestIf(launches: 3)
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/mezhevikin/AppReview